# Creating a web hook to invoke another URL with a delay

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sns, aws-api-gateway

What is the best AWS service or combination of service to create a web hook that does the following

1) Create web hook to return and close success immediately and collect URL and timeout.
2) Call the URL given after X seconds
3) X ranges from 0 seconds wait to say 60 seconds wait

So example the web hook will get call a URL after X seconds but it will close connection as successful immediately. Then it will invoke the url after X seconds. We need this to decouple a PHP script that we have in place now.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to write an AWS lambda function that calls the URL as required http://pastebin.com/V3eHdBnK

Then I have the an SNS topic subscription and pass SNS message {"url":"http://google.com", "timeout":10}

That works fine.